# Show that the sets $(A^B)^C$ and $A^{B \times C}$ have equal cardinality by constructing an explicit bijection between the two sets.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

(Exercise 3.6.6 in Analysis by Tao) Let $A, B, C$ be sets. Show that the sets $(A^B)^C$ and $A^{B \times C}$ have equal cardinality by constructing an explicit bijection between the two sets.

$A^B$ is the collection of all functions from $B$ to $A$. ($\{ g | g: B \to A\}$)

Attempt: We first have that $(A^B)^C = \{F | F : C \to \{g | g : B \to A\}\}$ and $A^{ B\times C} = \{f | f : B \times C \to A\}$.  I need to find the bijection $\omega : (A^B)^C \to A^{ B\times C} $.

Could you provide any hint to proceed from here?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57398/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/216471/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2278108/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(A%5EB)%5EC%24%2C%20%24A%5E%7BB%20%5Ctimes%20C%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Thanks. IT answers my question.